# (Unity 2D, C#) Issue instantiating Prefabs that shouldn't be instantiated

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, for-loop

## Background:

I'm trying to set up a system to spawn in a set amount of `GameObjects`, defined in the Menu Scene loaded before the Main Scene, into my game. I do this by running 3 `for` loops for the length of however many objects the user inputs in the Menu, with each loop run instantiating a copy of the Prefab.

## The Problem:

Whenever the Main Scene (Game Scene) is loaded from the menu, it always spawns at least 1 of each Prefab **even if the number is defined as 0 or** `null`. This is an issue, as it always adds a copy of each Prefab on top of the user defined amount.

**Partial Menu Image:**
[Menu segment for inputting values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8mEU.png)

**Images of Issue:**
[Spawned assets in scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTlK3.png)
[Assets in navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKLL0.png)

So far I've tried setting up multiple `Debug.Log();` -s throughout all the scripts that handle the numbers that are eventually parsed and passed to the spawning script itself (Data Managers, scriptable objs...) , as well as inside the spawning script itself. All the logs return the values as 0 and as such nothing *should* be spawning.

## Code of the Spawner Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PawnSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] VarManager VarManager;

    [SerializeField] GameObject Pawn;
    [SerializeField] GameObject InfPawn;
    [SerializeField] GameObject VaxPawn;

    private int? totPawns;
    private int? defPawns;
    private int? infPawns;
    private int? vaxPawns;

    private void Awake()
    {
        VarManager = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<VarManager>();

        totPawns = VarManager.totalPawns;

        defPawns = VarManager.uninfectedPawnAmount;
        infPawns = VarManager.infectedPawnAmount;
        vaxPawns = VarManager.vaccinatedPawnAmount;
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if(defPawns != 0 || defPawns != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= defPawns; i++)
            {
                int x = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-300, 301);
                int y = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-300, 301);

                GameObject D_Pawn = Instantiate(Pawn, new Vector3(x, y, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }

        if(infPawns != 0 || infPawns != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= infPawns; i++)
            {
                int x = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-300, 301);
                int y = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-300, 301);

                GameObject I_Pawn = Instantiate(InfPawn, new Vector3(x, y, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }

        if (vaxPawns != 0 || vaxPawns != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= vaxPawns; i++)
            {
                int x = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-300, 301);
                int y = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-300, 301);

                GameObject V_Pawn = Instantiate(VaxPawn, new Vector3(x, y, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Destroy(this);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        Debug.Log("---PAWN SPAWNER HAS FULLY EXECUTED SPAWNING SEQUENCE---");
        Debug.Log("TOTAL PAWNS SPAWNED:" + totPawns);
        Debug.Log("Default Pawns:" + defPawns);
        Debug.Log("Infected Pawns:" + infPawns);
        Debug.Log("Vaccinated Pawns:" + vaxPawns);
        Debug.Log("---REMOVING SELF---");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try putting breakpoints for each instantiate methods and see which one is spawning ?

Comment: @ÇağatayIŞIK I put 3 breakpoints on the IF statements, then 3 breakpoints on the Instatiate(); methods. All 3 if statements execute their code, and all 3 codes Instantiate an object even though the value is zero, and therefore the IF statement shouldn't execute. Here is a screenshot of the Breakpoints with all the values: https://prnt.sc/vSWP6aPA3QUo

Comment: Now that i look at your if ocnditions, they should be `&&` instead of `||` because since your values are 0 it means != null will be true and it will execute. Other thing is your loops should be `<` instead of `<=` because 0 == 0 will make it run once. I would remove the if conditions for good and change the for loops then you should be good.

Comment: @ÇağatayIŞIK Wait, is `int x = 0` the same thing as `int x = null` ?

Comment: No it is not. Since 0 means `!= null` it will go into if condition and your for loops makes it run once because your loops says `<=` instead of `<`